# How do I render MvcHtmlString as HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm getting MvcHtmlString as a model to my view. And I need to render this string as HTML. 
At the moment I tried to do:

```
@Model.ToHtmlString()
```

But it gives me plaint text on my page.
I know it should be like really trivial answer. But I can't get it =)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use the [`Html.Raw`](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2010/12/27/HtmlRawRazorViewEngine.aspx) helper:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.ToHtmlString())
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use

```
@(Model)
```

and implement in class the `ToHtmlString()` method